# Select multiples counts

Tags: mysql

My select:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT

   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM t_table 
   WHERE year(date) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2013' AND month(date) BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND date!=cad_em) as total1,

   (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM t_table
   WHERE year(date) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2013' AND month(date) BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND date=cad_em ) as total2

   FROM t_table
   GROUP BY date
```

Return:

```
total1 | total2
1        4
```

But I would like to return the date
Exemple:

```
date        | total1 | total2
2013-10     7          8
2013-11     1          4
2013-12     2          5
```

How could I do to show the same response to my example?

Thanks!!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT date,

Comment: Your select doesn't make any sense. You aggregate by a year calculating counts but then want to return those values for each date in the same table... Can you explain in plain words what are you trying to achieve? Better yet illustrate with a few rows of sample data and desired output. Apart from that use using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together and functions `YEAR()`, `MONTH()` in `WHERE` clause effectively causing fullscan for each subquery

Comment: I need the months and totals them

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional sum to simplify things. Also, I'm not sure your where condition makes a lot of sense, unless these are parameters -

```
select
date,
sum( if(date = cad_em, 0, 1) ) as total1,
sum( if(date = cad_em, 1, 0) ) as total2
from
t_table
where year(date) = 2013 and month(date) between 1 and 12
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select max(`date`) as `date`, sum(`date` <> cad_em) as total1, sum(`date` = cad_em) as total2
from t_table
where year(`date`) = 2013;
```

You see to want the maximum of the date, but that is just a guess.